# Jenkins - how do I find out who updated the global security settings

Tags: jenkins

Someone updated our global security and need to find out who did it.
Right now, using github authentication and the github commiter strategy.

The system logs (Manage Jenkins > System Log > All Jenkins Logs) show time and date, but not WHO.
Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin     . It provide   jobConfigHistory option. with help of this option you can see who made the change.

Comment: Thanks thats helpful.